# os.makedirs does not create folder on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am using python 3.7 and the following command to create a directory which works on linux but not on windows:

```
       try:
        #shutil.rmtree('../../dist')
        os.makedirs('../../dist')
    except OSError as e:
        print("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff")
        print(e)
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
```

Here is the error I get when I run it on windows:

```
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 
'../../dist'
```

and there is no dist folder at all and I have no idea what that error is

Any idea?

Comment: Are you *sure* `../../dist` doesn't exist? The error message says it does. Remember, relative paths are interpreted relative to the working directory, not the script's directory; I'd wager that if you `print`ed out `os.path.abspath('../../dist')` you'd find it's a path which exists (maybe an existing file, maybe an existing directory, but it's there).

Comment: Change `os.makedirs('../../dist')` to `os.makedirs('../../abcdefghijk')` and see if that works. Then see if it works a second time...

Comment: @ShadowRanger interesting when I print it, I see C:\dist but here is my python file path: C:\BNI-projects\tj-cfnservices1\tests\cfn so "../../dist" should point at "C:\BNI-projects\tj-cfnservices1" and not "c:\dist" any idea?

Comment: @HamedMinaee: The path to your Python script is irrelevant, like I said. Each program has a working directory (usually based on the directory you were in when you launched it, which is sometimes, but not always, the same as where the script is). If you launch the script via an IDE, or a custom shortcut or the like, the working directory can be almost anything. Try printing `os.getcwd()`; that's your working directory. If you need it to be relative to the script, you'd need to construct that path explicitly, e.g. `os.makedirs(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..', 'dist'))`

Comment: Possibly adding `os.path.abspath` around the `os.path.join` to get a cleaner looking path.

Comment: @ShadowRanger true. please add your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment as answer per OP's request:

The problem here is that you're providing a path relative to the script, but relative paths are interpreted relative to the process's working directory, which is often completely different from the script location. The directory already exists relative to the working directory, but you're looking at a path relative to the script, and (correctly) finding nothing there.

If the directory must be created relative to the script, change the code to:

```
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
# abspath is just to simplify out the path so error messages are plainer
# while os.path.join ensures the path is constructed with OS preferred separators
newdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(scriptdir, '..', '..', 'dist'))
os.makedirs(newdir)
```